# What is the formal name for this?

Tags: web-applications, language-agnostic, data-structures

What do you formally call an object whose only purpose is to read and cache (not write) a persistent storage entity (i.e. a database table)?

Examples of what I mean could be a localized language string reader that I could use like this:

```
Language.Get("hello_world", "en_US") // returns "Hello, world"
```

or a configuration reader, like this:

```
Config.Get("max_connections") // returns 3000
```

The reason I want to know is because I'm finding myself writing a lot of such objects and want to classify them correctly. "Model" didn't seem right to me because usually a model does write operations and more complex business logic. In this case the object only reads and caches.

Comment: You might just call it a cache. :-)

Comment: As you said - "its only purpose is to read and CACHE".. so call it cache! :) "In computer engineering, a cache is a component that transparently stores data so that future requests for that data can be served faster." (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

> Memoization is the act of "remembering" the results of a potentially expensive (but invariant) computation, so that it need not be recomputed. It is a way of implementing LazyEvaluation, and is a key feature in LazyFunctionalLanguage's, where it is done implicitly. Also, memoization doesn't require any "searching", generally--each memoized expression carries its "memo" with it, so it is easy to determine if the expression needs evaluating or not.
>
> Caching refers to the act of "remembering" an expensive computation or I/O. Caching can be read-only (in that the thing being cached cannot be modified), or read-write (in which case CacheCoherency becomes a problem). Also, the set of items in the cache may be much smaller than the set of items available for use (this is the case for memory system caches), in which case issues of cache allocation and replacement become important.